# swapping 2 number without using third temp

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I know how to swap 2 numbers without using temp variable. But this algorithm is not working if number is negative. how to solve that without using third variable.

```
a=a+b,
b=a-b
a=a-b
```

its not working if one of the number is `negative`.

Comment: Also, xor should work to swap variables without temp var

Comment: Just use a temporary variable. All the "clever" methods to avoid a temporary have various problems.

Comment: I just ran through it and it worked for me.

Comment: It works works for negative numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [Link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-two-numbers-without-using-temporary-variable/amp/) you can find different methods for swapping values in two variables without using a temp variable. It shows advantages and disadvantages.

It shows how to do it in 6 programming languages.

The following methods are extracted from the link:

Addition and subtraction:

```
x = x + y;
y = x - y;
x = x - y;
```

Multiplication and division:

```
x = x * y;
y = x / y;
x = x / y;
```

Xor:

```
x = x ^ y;
y = x ^ y;
x = x ^ y;
```

Mixture of bitwise and arithmetic operations:

```
a = (a & b) + (a | b);
b = a + (~b) + 1;
a = a + (~b) + 1;
```

Comment: I started to use stackoverflow actively a few days ago, so I'm fairly new here. Thank you for your suggestions. I've added to my answer the methods in the link for adding some context.

Answer (score 0):

The third line would be `a = a - b` and it also works for negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
x = x * y;

y = x / y; 

x = x / y;
```

will work only for non-zero numbers.

Comment: Think it through, put ```y=0```

Comment: and the `x * y` is susceptible to overflow